# Plugin Suggestions - Wordpress as a Membership Directory

Tags: plugins, directory, wordpress

I've been <strike>trying</strike> struggling over the last 2 weeks to find a viable way to configure a Wordpress installation as a membership directory that pulls information from user profiles (custom and default) and displays it in a presentable (possibly sortable) format.

Initially, something along the lines of the Sobi2 plugin for Joomla! was searched for, but to no avail. I stumbled on to a fairly straightforward blog entry on the subject, but it just seemed to list plugins without instructions on how to use them. see below.
http://www.cagintranet.com/archive/the-new-improved-way-to-turn-wordpress-27-into-a-membership-communit/

Any suggestions on decent plugins that can achieve what I'm looking for?
I'd like to avoid shelling out $175 for an enterprise plugin like aMember if possible.

Answer (score 5):

@Nick

You must go with DirectoryPress if cost is not barrier. This is excellent Directory Plugin. Check below link...
http://directorypress.net/

If you're looking for Free Plugins then here are few of them...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/business-directory-plugin/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/connections/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-easy-business-directory-1/

Answer (score 0):

check

- http://wpclassipress.com/demo/ which is similar to Sobi2